# In Magento, what's the performance of extending the rest/products api, to retrieve the tags and attributes of the products in the returned list?

Tags: php, api, rest, magento, product

The only way I can think of doing it is to retrieve the products, and then in the script call the other APIs to retrieve the information I need, before finally returning the response.

I'm still somewhat new to Magento, and this seems to be quite heavy on performance. Is the above solution effective in performance, or is there a better way of retrieving the tags,etc.. from the rest/products api?

Essentially, what I'm looking for is something along those lines:

The current API returns:

```
{
337: {
    entity_id: "337"
    type_id: "simple"
    sku: "ace000"
    color: "15"
    gender: "93"
    material: "130"
    jewelry_type: null
    description: "Gunmetal frame with crystal gradient polycarbonate lenses in grey. "
    meta_keyword: null
    short_description: "A timeless accessory staple, the unmistakable teardrop lenses of our Aviator sunglasses appeal to everyone from suits to rock stars to citizens of the world."
    name: "Aviator Sunglasses"
    meta_title: null
    meta_description: null
    regular_price_with_tax: 319.34
    regular_price_without_tax: 295
    final_price_with_tax: 319.34
    final_price_without_tax: 295
    is_saleable: true
    image_url: "http://magentogs.cloudapp.net/magento/media/catalog/product/cache/0/image/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/a/c/ace000a_1.jpg"
    }
}
```

I want to add the following (as an example), the ** include the things show the things I want to add.

```
{
337: {
    entity_id: "337"
    type_id: "simple"
    sku: "ace000"
    color: "15"
    gender: "93"
    material: "130"
    jewelry_type: null
    description: "Gunmetal frame with crystal gradient polycarbonate lenses in grey. "
    meta_keyword: null
    short_description: "A timeless accessory staple, the unmistakable teardrop lenses of our Aviator sunglasses appeal to everyone from suits to rock stars to citizens of the world."
    name: "Aviator Sunglasses"
    meta_title: null
    meta_description: null
    regular_price_with_tax: 319.34
    regular_price_without_tax: 295
    final_price_with_tax: 319.34
    final_price_without_tax: 295
    is_saleable: true
    image_url: "http://magentogs.cloudapp.net/magento/media/catalog/product/cache/0/image/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/a/c/ace000a_1.jpg"
    **tags: [tag1,tag2,tag3]**
    **categories: [category1,category2,category3]**
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should extend the existing product REST api model and override the method `_prepareProductForResponse` to include tags and other data

Check here overriding rest model http://web.archive.org/web/20130512072025/http://magepim.com/news/Extending-the-Magento-REST-API-part-1_13

Your model definition:

```
Namespace_yourmodule_Model_Catalog_Api2_Product_Rest extends Mage_Catalog_Model_Api2_Product_Rest {


protected function _prepareProductForResponse(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product $product)
{
 // keep the existing code as it is

 // now add new code to add tags

 $productData['tags'] = Mage::getModel('tag/tag')->getResourceCollection()
    ->addPopularity()
    ->addProductFilter($product->getId());


// in the end 
 $product->addData($productData);
}
```